# solving $\int\frac{2x^3}{x^2+1} \, dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int\frac{2x^3}{x^2+1} \, dx$$

$$u=x^2$$

$$du=2x \, dx$$

$$\int \frac{u}{u+1} \, du$$$$=\int \frac{u+1-1}{u+1}du$$$$=\int 1-\frac{1}{u+1} \, du$$

how should I continue? is there an algotherm for integrating rational functions?

Comment: **HINT**: Use the substitution $v=1+u$ next

Comment: I really do not understand what your problem/question is.

Comment: You have come real close and then complete it as $u - ln(|u+1|)$.  That is the reason why Ron is puzzled.

Comment: @Mufasa why should I use substitution?

Comment: You should just know that $\int\dfrac1{x+a}\,dx=\ln|x+a|$. It should be in your table. Either an allowed cheat sheet, or (preferrably) the table in your head.

Comment: Because that will then simplify your integral of $$\int\frac{1}{u+1}du$$to:$$\int \frac{1}{v}dv$$which I assume you know how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, here is another simple method, $$\int \frac{2x^3}{x^2+1}\ dx$$
$$\int \frac{2x^3+2x-2x}{x^2+1}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{2x(x^2+1)-2x}{x^2+1}\ dx$$
$$=\int 2x\ dx-\int \frac{2x}{x^2+1}\ dx$$
$$=2\int x\ dx-\int \frac{d(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}$$
$$=\color{red}{x^2-\ln(x^2+1)+C}$$

Comment: Nice solution. Exactly how I would have proceeded. +1

Comment: Umpteenth time this is done on the site. Did you search for a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

So far you have $\int 1 du - \int \frac{du}{u + 1}$.

Make the substitution $v = u + 1 \implies dv = du$ You get:

$u + c - \int \frac{dv}{v} = u - \ln\mid v \mid +\text{ } C$

Re substitute and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

No need of sub :

Just put $$2x^3=2x(1+x^2)-2x$$

Comment: How would you continue?